# Why do snails come out after the rain?

Tags: zoology, ethology

Many times, when there is rain after a *long time*, snails come out afterwards, and you can see snails and slugs everywhere! I have two questions:

1. Why do they come out after the rain?
2. Where are they usually found, not after a rain?

Note that I do emphasize when there is a rain "after a long time"

Comment: They probably need oxygen. If they are living in the dirt, then the water will force them to the surface.

Comment: A [yahoo answer post](https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070327101451AAJcd3i) suggest that they come out to flee drowning as @AMR suggested.

Comment: Snail Behavior Rain... 20,400 results; Snail Locomotion Rain 4,520 results; Snail Movement Rain... 22,500 results.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25100934#25100934

Answer (score 5):

In most species, slugs and snails survive droughts (which would otherwise kill them by dehydration) by creating "slime tombs" (initially-viscous bubbles of slime) around themselves. these tombs or pellets will quickly dry out, on the surface, while resisting total dehydration. When it rains, these capsules will re-hydrate or "melt," beginning on the surface, and the creatures will crawl free. 
Because they've gone without food, they're ravenous, and go everywhere, "rasping" softened nutrients from the surfaces of plants and even objects where "blossoming" single-cell organisms (also recently re-hydrated) can be found.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Can you please add references? (I am not trying to be rude) I like your answer, but references would certainly complete it.